# How to implement OnSelectionChanged event for a TFileListBox?

Tags: delphi

I want to create a new event for TFileListBox. I want to know when the user selects a different item.

The best way to implement it will be to call the event when the user presses the mouse button like this:

```
procedure TMyFileList.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
VAR PrevItem: Integer;
begin
 PrevItem:= ItemIndex; <---------- Problem here
 inherited;
 if (Count> 0)
 AND ( PrevItem<> ItemIndex )                                                  
 AND Assigned(FOnSelChaged)
 then FOnSelChaged(Self, PrevItem);
end;
```

So, let's say the fist item (ItemIndex=0) was already selected.
As soon as I push down the mouse button to select the second item, I enter the MouseDown procedure. But here the ItemIndex is already 1 instead of 0.
Why?

Comment: which version of Delphi?

Comment: It appears that your assumption about where the selection changes was incorrect. Clearly, the selection changes earlier. Find that place instead. I could help, but I have no idea what TFileList is, so I cannot read its source code.

Comment: Sorry. I am speaking indeed about tFileListBox. The code behaves the same under Delphi 7/XE.

Comment: @Rob: It's `TFileListBox`, from the Win 3.1 component palette. I really, really wish EMBT would mark all the stuff on that tab as `deprecated` and remove them entirely; no one is doing Windows 3.1 apps with 32-bit (or 64-bit) Delphi or Builder, and removing them would get rid of the apps still looking like they're pre-Win 95. No offense intended, Altar. :) I get irritated every time I see a recently-written app that looks fine on XP or Win7 *until* you go to open a file and see that antiquated TDirectoryListBox / TFileListBox based dialog.

Comment: @Ken - There is any Delphi-embedded alternative to TFileListBox?

Comment: @Altar You are looking for TShellListView: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ShellControls_Sample

Comment: TShellListView is weird. Probably this is why Borland/Embarcadero does not install it by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TFileListBox` maintains a protected field named `FLastSel` which is exactly what you need. The other big problem with your code is that you are assuming that selection can only be changed by the mouse. Don't forget about the keyboard or programmatic modification. You are looking for the virtual method named `Change`.

So, putting it all together, you can do what you need like this:

```
TMyFileListBox = class(TFileListBox)
protected
  procedure Change; override;
.... 

procedure TMyFileListBox.Change;
begin
  if (Count>0) and (FLastSel<>ItemIndex) and Assigned(FOnSelChanged) then        
    FOnSelChanged(Self, FLastSel, ItemIndex);
  inherited;
end;
```

We have to make use of `FLastSel` before we call the inherited `Change` method since that is where `FLastSel` is changed to be equal to the current selection.

```
procedure TFileListBox.Change;
begin
  FLastSel := ItemIndex;
  .... continues
```

Comment: I know about it. But it isn't what I need. I want one event that can show the previously selected item.

Comment: It took me a little while to work out exactly what you need but I think I got there in the end.

Comment: +1. Nice effort to solve this for a component I *know* you're not familiar with, David. :)

Comment: @ken yes, it was a journey into the great unknown

Comment: And the ancient, lost world of Delphi 1. :)